# optimizing join statement in mysql joining 4 tables

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

How could I optimize the below query? It's taking far too long to run.
The main main tables (relev_annot, ranks_pearson, norm_alls, smoothby2) are all 16400 rows (and have the same number of identical identifiers). The other 2 tables (CClist, bgo_FGH) are only 35 and 1800 rows, respectively.

This is the query that I've been running:

```
select relev_annots.*, CClist.corecc_gene, bgo_FGH.*, ranks_pearson.*, norm_alls.*, smoothby2.*
from relev_annots 
join smoothby2 on smoothby2.pt3 = relev_annots.pt3 
join norm_alls on norm_alls.pt3 = relev_annots.pt3
join ranks_pearson ON ranks_pearson.pt3 = relev_annots.pt3
left join CClist on CClist.pt2_kegg_id = relev_annots.pt3_kegg_hit
LEFT JOIN bgo_FGH ON bgo_FGH.pt3 = relev_annots.pt3
```

Thanks.

Comment: No where clause or extra conditions on the joins... Are you surprised it's slow?

Comment: i am actually, but that's just because I have not much clue what to  do else.. a where clause thus. I have no idea what kind of where clause I could add.. In my limited understanding the `ON` statement functions as a `where`, but I guess I'm wrong..? thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Do you need all 16400 results? If so, then there's likely not much you can do, assuming appropriate indices. Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name_here` for each of the tables so we can inspect your index structure to make sure they are appropriate.

Comment: Well.. this seems to be the part that I have been missing in my crash course MySQL. I didn't index tables and now that I did, it runs like a charm...

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.